# Stop page from scrolling past specified Div (or Footer element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Seemingly, this question has been asked several times, but not with my specific situation / needs.

I recently had a product filter developed for an eCommerce site. It's working fine, however, the setup involves the products that have been 'filtered out' being sent out of view at the bottom of the site.
Whilst they are out of view to the customer, the browser still allocates space for them at the bottom, hence my site now scrolls well past the footer.

My Question is;
Is it possible to lock off scrolling at a certain part of a page using jQuery or CSS?

eg; stop scrolling at base of footer. Or slot in an Div with an ID at the bottom of the page and spec no scrolling past that?

Many thanks in advance.

Damien

Comment: It's possible, but that would be a solution to a problem that you shouldn't be having in the first place. It's like asking "how do I stop the bleeding whenever I sit on a sharp nail"... I can tell you to put a bandage on, or I can tell you to not sit on a sharp nail in the first place.

In this case, why would you move the products to the bottom of the site/page? Instead, just add the css `display: none;` to those elements instead, to completely hide them. Or possibly you can even just remove the elements from the page entirely instead?

Comment: Try giving the parent container of the filtered items a style of overflow: hidden. I could give more details if I knew a bit more about the structure of the markup

Comment: Thanks for both your replies Hamza Kubba & Wunth.

Comment: Hamza I agree I shouldn't even have had to worry  about it as the script should have been written differently. Thanks for your suggested solution.

Comment: Wunth - I ran with your simple fix Overflow:hidden and it worked a treat. Due to privacy I wasn't able to post a link to the site. Anyway, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KwgMj/184/

You can handle scroll event and then restrict the scroll for any given value.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {   
    if($(window).scrollTop() >=150) {
       $(window).scrollTop(150);
    }
});
```

Just replace the "150" by the y-position of desired div.

Comment: Thanks Vijay! I will add that piece of js to my library. Cheers!